# Requirements to view Board and Card Games StackExchange Website

Tags: support

I have recently found this website and wished to share the particular questions pertaining to Bridge with a friend of mine in the UK so I sent them the following link but they said it wouldn't work. Is this because it is in Beta at the moment, is it a country specific website or something else?

link used:
https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bridge

Comment: What happened -- did your friend get a 404 (page not found), or did it fail in some other way?

Comment: Was there any downtime recently?

Comment: Apparently it just timed out. As for downtime, I have no idea.

Comment: I suggested finding Stack Exchange through google but that timed out too

Answer (score 6):

The Beta is public, and available to all. It doesn't even require a log in. And Stack Exchange doesn't filter based on country.

Your friend's problem is downstream. Corporate firewall, or perhaps overzealous parental controls?

You can always take a look at http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ if you aren't sure if a site is up.

Answer (score 5):

If the link is currently available to your friend, but wasn't before, then it might have been because of database issues that occurred recently. Checking [StackStatus.net](http://stackstatus.net/)

> Database Issue Feb. 5th 2013
>
> Our primary SQL Server experienced a “non yielding scheduler” and wrote a 234 GB memory dump to disk before restarting. During this time all sites were offline. After the crash dump completed SQL was able to start without issue. We will continue to monitor the server and have plans to switch all of our sites back over to NY this weekend which are running on fully patched SQL 2012 instances. Stay tuned…